# Vim highlight similar including special characters

Tags: vim

Pressing shift + * will highlight similar words in vim, however, word seems to be the part of a string up to the next special character. So, if my marker is on the s of `the-string-I-want-to find` it would highlight all instances of 'string' in the file.

Is there a way that I can do the same but instead of searching for the subset, it searches for the whole string `the-string-I-want-to find`?

Comment: `set isk+=-`. However this may mess up your "words"

Comment: works fine for those characters, but my 'words' also include : which does not seem to be accepted as keyword. set isk=+-: gives an error 'trailing characters'

Comment: @user1734278 `+=` not `=+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` command works on *words*; which characters belong to that group is controlled (per buffer) by the `'iskeyword'` option. As Peter Rincker already commented, you can manipulate that via

```
:setlocal isk+=-
```

(Or use `:set` e.g. in `~/.vimrc` to change this globally.) Be aware that this also affects other commands, like the navigation with `w`, `e`, etc.,  and potentially even syntax highlighting.

Alternatively, there are plugins that extend the `*` mapping to visual mode, so you can search for arbitrary text fragments by selecting them first. My [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) offers this and has a list of alternatives.

Comment: Since more and more people are using Lua now, it would be nice to include a lua version: `vim.opt.iskeyword:append({'-'})`.

https://neovim.discourse.group/t/adding-special-characters-to-iskeyword/942

Comment: _more and more people are using Lua now_ [citation needed]; I thought Vim 9's new scripting language is the latest fad?

Answer (score 0):

Vim is a very bad editor without customization. Add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
function! s:VSetSearch()
let old = @"
norm! gvy
let @/ = '\V' . substitute(escape(@", '\'), '\n', '\\n', 'g')
let @" = old
endfunction

" * and # search for next/previous of selected text when used in visual mode
vnoremap * :<C-u>call <SID>VSetSearch()<CR>/<CR>
vnoremap # :<C-u>call <SID>VSetSearch()<CR>?<CR>
```

Now what you do is highlight what you want to search for with <kbd>v</kbd> and then hit <kbd>*</kbd>. With this mapping it will do the same thing as what `*` does, but to your visual selection.